# Is it possible to produce sulfuric acid at large scale by oxidizing and hydrating pyrite?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I was reading *The Knowledge* by Lewis Dartnell, which is a book about recreating our technology from scratch should we experience a civilization-ending apocalypse. The author thinks that acquiring vanadium catalyst for contact process is too difficult, so his recommendation to produce sulfuric acid is to: (1) bake pyrite, (2) react the sulfur dioxide produced with chlorine gas (electrolyzed from brine), using activated carbon as the catalyst, (3) then react the resulting sulfuryl chloride with water to produce sulfuric acid.

I don't know how hard acquiring vanadium is, but I think it will be easier to replicate the same process happening in [acid mine drainage](http://www.westech-inc.com/en-usa/industry-solutions/mineral-overview/acid-mine-drainage):
$$\ce{2 FeS2 + 7 O2 + 2 H2O → 2 FeSO4 + 2 H2SO4}$$

The iron(II) sulfate can then be baked to produce sulfur trioxide, which can also be processed into sulfuric acid.

I think this method would have been simpler. Am I correct? Is there another simple method of producing sulfuric acid?

Comment: Well, you want to produce sulfuric acid which is reasonably highly concentrated. Because as a dilute acid, it´s not so very useful.

Comment: Distillation shouldn't be too hard, no? Sulfuric acid also has a much higher boiling point than water, so boiling should be good enough in a pinch.

Comment: Have you ever tried to distill even pure water? I guarantee you sulfuric acid is far, far worse. Plus I bet it´s an azeotrope. And definitely badly corrosive. ;-)

Comment: A post-apocalyptic world should be littered with broken stainless-steel tools. A lot of the items in my toolbox are embossed with names that spell xx*vanad*yy.

Comment: @Karl Thankfully, I have never needed to distill sulfuric acid, but I'm aware of the danger. Will the method I proposed make a very dilute acid, or at least more dilute than what the book recommended? Also, what's _xxvanadyy_? Google gave nothing on that.

Comment: Hm, acid mine drainage gives very dilute acid, bad enough for the environment, but I guess far less than 1 mol/l. If you do the reaction on purpose, it might be possible to be far better.

Comment: @Karl To the best of my knowledge, acid mine drainage is dilute only because it's exposed to the environment eg. rainwater, river. I'm guessing that performing the reaction on a sealed environment would result in a much higher concentration. I've never done anything like that, though, so nothing conclusive.

Comment: The *xxvanadyy* thing was simply referring to the fact that steel tools are often chromium vanadium alloys. See here for one in my own toolbox: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4757/79678. I will delete this comment in a day or two.

Comment: @Karl The H2SO4-H2O azeotrope IS concentrated sulfuric acid (98.3%). H2SO4 has a boiling point that is much higher than water (290°C pure, 338°C for the azeotrope).

Comment: If your already using electricity, you could make O3 or H2O2 using electric arcs, and they should be able to oxidize SO2 to SO3 or H2SO4. That's very energy-intensive, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per a source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/iron-bacteria), there is an iron bacteria path acting on FeS2 to create sulfuric acid:

> Thiobacillus spp. are participants of active oxidative corrosion. They oxidize a range of sulfur compounds to sulfuric acid, and the acid released from the cells may attack alloys.

My experience, however, suggests that the easiest way to produce H2SO4 is by the action of a concentrated solution of Oxalic acid (used in commercial products) on magnesium sulfate (FeSO4 may also work, but likely leads to an iron impurity).

Per a source (old [Wikipedia commentary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalate)) to quote:

> Relationship to oxalic acid
>
> The dissociation of protons from oxalic acid proceeds in a stepwise manner as for other polyprotic acids. Loss of a single proton results in the monovalent hydrogenoxalate anion HC2O4−. A salt with this anion is sometimes called an acid oxalate, monobasic oxalate, or hydrogen oxalate."

As such expected reactions:

$\ce{MgSO4 + 2 H2C2O4 -> Mg(HC2O4)2 + H2SO4}$

$\ce{MgSO4 + Mg(HC2O4)2 -> 2 MgC2O4 (s) + H2SO4}$

Be careful, the created Sulfuric acid could be very strong depending on the level of hydration.

Warning: Attempting (in the presence of H2C2O4) to produce fuming sulfuric by boiling down the solution can lead to a spontaneous ejection of the acid (reported in an [old thread](https://www.sciencemadness.org/whisper/viewthread.php?tid=18963&page=2#pid261189) of mine).